# Customised xml using JSON object

Tags: javascript, xml, json, node.js

I am trying to create a customised xml with the help of JSON object. Below is my data.

```
var data = {
  "title": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "firstName": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "lastName": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "age": {
        "description": "Age in years",
        "type": "integer",
        "minimum": 0
      }
    },
    "required": {
      details: {
        Questions: [
          {
            othersTitle: "mr",
            title: "aa",
            firstName: "xyz"
          },
          {
            othersTitle: "mrs",
            title: "bb",
            firstName: "abc"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
var dataPath = data.required.details.Questions[].title;
```

> Since there are two datas in an array, how can I create two xml tag.

```
var xmlPath = userDetails[0].custInfo[].userList.title;
```

I have added my small piece of logic [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/user87267867/226vtp5a/) on how I am creating a single xml tag with one JSON array data. How can I make my call recurisve to create mutiple xml for serval array data.
Any help on this will be really helpful.

Comment: your fiddle is very confusing. can you post the xml format you require here?

Comment: @AbdulJabbar i have added new (JSFIDDLE)[http://jsfiddle.net/user87267867/xgn7ogar/ ] which can be more clear

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/user87267867/xgn7ogar/1/